# Changing layout element order in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layouts, arcgis-pro, element, draw-order

I cannot find an option to change the order of Layout elements in ArcGIS Pro (1.3.1).  This is where you right-click > Order on a map element and choose from Bring to Front, Send to Back, Bring Forward, Send Backward.

Example from ArcMap:
[image]

Whereas in ArcGIS Pro there is no *Order* option in the right-click context menu:
[image]

Also no option in the Element Properties dialogs:
[image]

[image]

I have found that the order that I place the elements dictates the order that they draw (the elements I add last are drawn on top).  If I delete an element that is below another, then redraw it, it will be placed on top.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking to choose the draw order of layout elements in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer right after I asked the question.  The Table of Contents lists Draw Order for layouts.  You can select any map element in this draw order and change the order they draw in the layout.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone who sees this thread is using QGIS, there is no need to change any settings on the Table of Contents to adjust this. You just need to click and drag the elements so that they are arranged from top to bottom drawing order.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]